# How define a global variable with an input box without using a callback function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, callback, plotly-dash

I am using Dash in python. I have a search box, that takes the input value.
Unluckily the rest of my code starts and needs a global variable that is the result of the input text box. As the input box has the callback function, I need to define a global variable that changes this variable as soon you insert a new value in the input box.
This never happens as the code start with the variable that never changes the value when I insert the new value in the input box.
How can I define a variable with an input box without using a callback function? I need something as input() in python but with an input text box.

```
search_bar = dbc.Row([
html.Div(id="output_ricerca2"),
dbc.Input(id="input", placeholder="Stock...", type="text")
])    

value='test' #i would here the value of input box as variable
    other code using this value

page_1_layout = html.Div([
    html.Br(),
    html.H1('Page 1')
#I need here the update value of the input box
])
@app.callback(Output('output_ricerca2', 'children'),
                [Input('output_ricerca', 'n_clicks')],
                #[Input('btn-submit', 'n_clicks')],
                [State('url', 'pathname')])
def update_output(clicks, pathname):
    if clicks is not None:
        result_titolo=pathname.split("/"),
        print('path:'),
        print(result_titolo)
        return (result_titolo)

    
@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('page-content2', 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/Overview':
        return page_1_layout
    elif pathname == '/PricePerformance':
        return page_2_layout
    elif pathname == '/BalanceSheet':
        return page_3_layout
    elif pathname == '/Graphs':
        return page_4_layout
    elif pathname == '/Competitors':
        return page_5_layout
    else:
        return ''
    
    @app.callback(Output("output_ricerca", "children"), [Input("input", "value")])
        def update_output(value):
                apiurl = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search?q="+value
                r = requests.get(apiurl)
                data = r.json()
                if data['quotes']:
                    exchange = data["quotes"][0]['exchange']
                    print(exchange)
                    table_rows = [html.Tr([dcc.Link(href=z.get('symbol'),children=[z.get('symbol')]),html.Td(z.get('longname')),html.Td(z.get('quoteType')+'-'+z.get('exchange'))]) for z in data['quotes']]
                    #rows_longname = [html.Tr([html.Td(z.get('longname'))]) for z in data['quotes']]
                    output_table = html.Div(
                    html.Table([ 
                    html.Th(scope="row",
                            children=[
                    html.Td('Symbols'),
                    ])
                    ]+table_rows), 
                        style={})
                return output_table
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unluckily the rest of my code starts and needs a global variable that is the result of the input text box

I think this is actually the problem here. Trying to use a global variable like you're describing runs contrary to React/Dash and the callback structure.

If the rest of your code runs from that value, then set up the callback so it will `raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate` if the input still has the default value. Here's an example:

```py
@app.callback(Output("output_ricerca", "children"), [Input("input", "value")])
def update_output(value):
    if not value:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    # the rest of your code...
```

Or, if you set a default for that component like `value='foo'` then your condition could be `if value == 'foo'`

Comment: where do you set the value='foo', before the callback function, right? outside the dcc.Input(id='input', value='Initial Value',type='text')?

Comment: i edited the question maybe now is more clear. I need that value='test' is the default value of the input box. But this never happens. I do not know how to do this

Comment: Yes, set the `dcc.Input(value='test'...` and then have everything run off the callback that listens to that prop changing.

Comment: yeah but doesn't work. 
example:
@app.callback(Output('output_ricerca2', 'children'),
                [Input('output_ricerca', 'n_clicks')],
                #[Input('btn-submit', 'n_clicks')],
                [State('url', 'pathname')])
def update_output(clicks, pathname):
    if clicks is not None:
        result_titolo=pathname.split("/"),
        return (result_titolo[1])

How you get result_titolo[1] as a variable not in a div but in a variable?

Comment: You mean in order to use it elsewhere? You'd then use the `children` of `output_ricerca2` as the `Input` to another callback where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do this:

```
search_bar = dbc.Row([
html.Div(id="output_ricerca2"),
dbc.Input(id="input", placeholder="Stock...", type="text")
])    
value='test'
```

the variable value is different by the value of the input box. I need them are the same variable. I need that the value of the input box will be defined as global. Valid for all code and can be changed by the input box.